# Is $\mathbb{E}[|X_n|]$ finite for $0<X_n<1, \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: probability-theory

If $0<X_n<1, \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, can I conclude that $\mathbb{E}[|X_n|]$ is finite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may conclude $E|X_n| \le 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks. Is this because $0<X_n<1$?

Comment: Any average of numbers in a closed interval lies in that interval.