# Does $X_n=\binom {n} {k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ have finite expectation?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $0<p<1$.

Let $X_n=\binom {n} {k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$. Based on the definition of $X_n$, can I conclude that the $0<X_n<1$?

Finally, can I conclude that $\mathbb{E}[|X_n|]<1$ for all $n$?

Comment: $X_n$ is a probability from the binomial distribution. And by definition, probabilities are between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Thanks, can I conclude that $\mathbb{E}[|X_n|]<1$ for all $n$? I know $\mathbb{E}[|X|]=x_n\cdot p_1 + \dots +x_n \cdot p_n$, but what exactly would be the definition of $\mathbb{E}[|X_n|]$?

Comment: $X_n$ as defined is not quite a random variable (OK, it is a random variable which happens to be constant). Indeed the constant r.v. $X_n$ has expectation $\le 1$, since it is a constant $\le 1$.  But I expect there is some confusion here, with a mistranscription of the real question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $X_n(k) \geq 0$ for any $0 \leq k \leq n$ and $p \in [0,1]$. Now by the binomial theorem, $$(a + b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} a^k b^{n-k}.$$ Take $a = p$ and $b = 1-p$ to get $$1 = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} = \sum_{k=0}^n X_n(k).$$ So $X_n(k) \geq 0$ and they add up to $1$, hence they must all be between $0$ and $1$. And from your [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150536/is-mathbbex-n-finite-for-0x-n1-forall-n-in-mathbbn) you already know that if $X_n \in [0,1]$ then $E[|X_n|] \leq 1$.